# Label Format does not fit in database - PHP 7.1 json_encode() and serialize_precision

Tags: address-labels, php7

I am encountering this error when attempting to define a new label format, "Sorry an error occurred", "Label Format does not fit in database.".

This is on CiviCRM 5.8.1 on Joomla 3.9.1. I can't reproduce it on dmaster.

- Administer > Communications > Label Formats
- Click Add Label Format
  button
- I used the format settings below:

[image: Label format settings that I used]

But if I entered at least some of the measurements as integer numbers only, I am able to save the new label format.

Looking at the civicrm_option_value table in the database, value looks like:

`{"paper-size":"a4","orientation":"portrait","font-name":"helvetica","font-size":9,"font-style":"","NX":3,"NY":11,"metric":"in","lMargin":0.25,"tMargin":0.5500000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125,"SpaceX":0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625,"SpaceY":0,"width":2.520000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125,"height":0.95999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375,"lPadding":1,"tPadding":1}`

The very long floating-point numbers look like the cause of the problem. The db column is a varchar(512).

To work around this I had to finish entering the last two values directly in the database table after editing the long numbers back to 1 or 2 decimal places.

Has anybody encountered this before?

---

**UPDATE:**
This has arisen since PHP 7.1. See this [StackExchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981409/php7-1-json-encode-float-issue/43056278): *"According to documentation, PHP 7.1.x started to use serialize_precision instead of precision when encoding double values."*

In `CRM_Core_BAO_LabelFormat::saveLabelFormat()` this line uses `json_encode`:

`$this->value = json_encode($v);`

`$v` is OK, it will contain something like:

`array(16) {
  ["paper-size"]=>
  string(2) "a4"
  ["orientation"]=>
  string(8) "portrait"
  ["font-name"]=>
  string(9) "helvetica"
  ["font-size"]=>
  int(10)
  ["font-style"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["NX"]=>
  int(3)
  ["NY"]=>
  int(11)
  ["metric"]=>
  string(2) "in"
  ["lMargin"]=>
  float(0.25)
  ["tMargin"]=>
  float(0.55)
  ["SpaceX"]=>
  float(0.1)
  ["SpaceY"]=>
  float(0)
  ["width"]=>
  float(2.52)
  ["height"]=>
  float(0.96)
  ["lPadding"]=>
  float(0.12)
  ["tPadding"]=>
  float(0.1)
}`

It is only after the json_encode() that the extra-long floats are present:

`string(546) "{"paper-size":"a4","orientation":"portrait","font-name":"helvetica","font-size":10,"font-style":"","NX":3,"NY":11,"metric":"in","lMargin":0.25,"tMargin":0.5500000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125,"SpaceX":0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625,"SpaceY":0,"width":2.520000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125,"height":0.95999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375,"lPadding":0.11999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875,"tPadding":0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625}"`

Inserting `ini_set('serialize_precision', -1 );` into `CRM_Core_BAO_LabelFormat::saveLabelFormat()` before the `json_encode()` makes it work for me, as does adding it to php.ini but I'm not sure what the proper solution is.

Does this affect CiviCRM elsewhere? Would this be considered a CiviCRM issue? Or something that should at least be documented (the need to set it in php.ini)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm that this is a bug in civicrm. I was able to replicate on my local running PHP 7.1.

I've created a Gitlab issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/612